# Order confirmation emails not working in Magento 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

My website is live and the order confirmation emails are neither being sent to the customer nor the admin. I am using Magento 1.9.3.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check whether **Cron jobs** are working or not, you can check easily by installing [AOE SCHEDULER](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) extension, make sure you have proper setting in `System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Cron` Also check whether you entered sender email in `System > configuration> Sales> Sales email > Order emails.`

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the above, out of the box the cronjobs are pre-configured in Magento, but you need to setup the actual job on your servers cron tab.

In SSH open the crontab;

```
crontab -e
```

Add this;

```
### MAGENTO CRON ###
*/1 * * * * cd /path/to/magento/ && sh cron.sh
```

Replaced /path/to/magento with the actual path your installation.

Answer (score 0):

Magento allow 2 way to send email like below :

1) Using cron
2) Avoid cron

If you want without cron then use below change:

Open your order.php file at - app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

And change :

```
//$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); **// Comment this code.**
```

to:

```
$mailer-> send();
```

**Note** : **Above change is not standard way in magneto so please implement file override way.**

Go to : app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml:

Add following code on the top of the file code :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId(); 
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
try
{ 
  $order->sendNewOrderEmail();
} 
catch (Exception $ex) 
{ 
  echo "Email Not Sent..."; 
}
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$email = $customer->getEmail();
```

Comment: Hi, I used the second method and it's working. But the problem now is that an order email is being sent to the admin but not to the customer who placed an order.The customer should also receive the email. How do I sort that out?